# How to find specific keys using specific values in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have 2 lists that contain months and total sales in that month and then I combined them into a dictionary. But I have a problem when trying to find which month have sales higher than average total sales. The code that I wrote just shows all months. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
total_sales = [1500,2250,1850,2000,2500,2400,2000,2100,2200,2800,2000,2750]

print('\n')

sales_per_month = dict(zip(months, total_sales))
print(sales_per_month)

print('\n')

average_sales = sum(sales_per_month.values())/len(sales_per_month.values())
print(average_sales)

print('\n')

for sales in sales_per_month.values():
  if sales > average_sales:
    print(sales_per_month.keys())
  else:
    pass
```

I have feeling that I was wrong when I wrote the looping part, but maybe I also did something wrong in other parts.

Comment: You are printing all keys in that dictionary not just this value's key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it for you:

```
months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
total_sales = [1500,2250,1850,2000,2500,2400,2000,2100,2200,2800,2000,2750]

print('\n')

sales_per_month = dict(zip(months, total_sales))
print(sales_per_month)

print('\n')

average_sales = sum(sales_per_month.values())/len(sales_per_month.values())
print(average_sales)

print('\n')
for month, sales in sales_per_month.items():
    if sales > average_sales:
        print(month, sales)
    else:
        continue
```

output:

```
Feb 2250
May 2500
Jun 2400
Sep 2200
Oct 2800
Dec 2750
```